# SVN Merge back removed changeset

Tags: svn, commit, changeset

Awhile ago a changeset (revision 55) was updated to SVN and then removed(revision 56). I now need this changeset back. The current revision is 1010.

How can this be done? Again I only want the changes for revision 54 to 55 to be added to revision 1010, and all the changes made since revision 56 to remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run the following command:

```
svn merge -r 54:55
```

Comment: I think this is command is correct, but its not working for me. when I try it, it acts like there are no changes to make (returns to new command line). I even tried reversing it (55:54) and svn status wont show any changes. if I diff 54 and 55 it does return a number of changes. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @JavaBeast - RTFM, and reverse merge r56 (`svn merge -c -56`) in order to return reverse-merge performed by r56 back

Comment: @Lazy- Worked great! post as an answer and I'll accept, thanks!